# java: Non-Recursive Depth First Search using ArrayDeque or LinkedList or LinkedBlockingDeque?

Tags: java, depth-first-search, non-recursive

```
public void traverse(Node root){
    ArrayDeque<Node> queue = new ArrayDeque<Node>();
        queue.add(root);

    while(!queue.isEmpty()){
        Node currentNode = queue.pollFirst();   
        List<Node> nl = getChildrenfromDB(currentNode);
        queue.addAll(nl);
    }
```

so should I be using `ArrayDeque` or `LinkedList` or `LinkedBlockingDeque`? what would happen when I set int value of 10? Does this mean the queue will only hold 10 at a time? what if the Collection retrieved from DB's size is larger than 10? Is this bound value define the "snapshot" of the queue?

```
public void traverse(Node root){
    LinkedBlockingDeque<Node> queue = new LinkedBlockingDeque<Node>(10);
        queue.add(root);

    while(!queue.isEmpty()){
        Node currentNode = queue.pollFirst();   
        List<Node> nl = getChildrenfromDB(currentNode);
        queue.addAll(nl);
    }
```

Comment: Code a prepend.  For a queue, this shouldn't be very hard.

Comment: What about `List.addAll(int index, Collection<? extends E> c)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an `ArrayList` -- use one of the implementations of the `Deque` interface. For example, use a `LinkedBlockingDeque`, which is designed for this sort of thing. Use the `addFirst()`, `addLast()`, `pollFirst()`, and `pollLast()` methods as needed.

If, for some reason, you really need to use a `List`, use a `LinkedList` -- adding to the front of an `ArrayList` is extremely inefficient, as all elements need to be moved.

Answer (score 1):

You could read the javadocs for [ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

> public void add(int index, E element)
>
> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list. Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).

```
queue.add(0,myObject);
```

JavaDocs are your *friend*.

That being said, as others have mentioned; not the best data structure to use. If you don't need random access into the list, a LinkedList or ArrayDeque are more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you use Stacks. Stack is the way to go for DFS. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) article to see why Stack will solve the problem. See this useful [tutorial](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=graphsDataStrucs2) also :)

Comment: I have used it but it uses a lot of memory.